# FancyBox won't "pop"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fancybox

I've been trying for 2 hours to get FancyBox to work and have no clue how it isn't working. Obviously I am missing something because it's just linking to the image.

Example: I link the image to my images folder (both the thumb and the large image), and when I click the image it just takes me to a new page and shows me the image rather than popping up.

Here is my code:

```
<head>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/stylish-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylish-portfolio/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylish-portfolio/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylish-portfolio/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" media="screen"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylish-portfolio/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylish-portfolio/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylish-portfolio/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylish-portfolio/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylish-portfolio/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancyImg").fancybox();
});
        </script></head>


    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <a class="fancyImg" href="img/portfolio-2.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="img/portfolio-2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Any JS errors in the console?

Comment: you either need to load the normal or the pack version of fancybox js file, but not both

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is your are loading fancybox twice. Pick one.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylish-portfolio/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylish-portfolio/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the html body section I added this code

```
<a class="fancyImg" href="img1.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="img1.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".fancyImg").fancybox();
                    type:"iframe"
                    });
        </script>
```

And it seems to be working fine :)

Comment: You don't need to open images as `iframe`

Comment: No you are right. I just added a type when I was checking it out